# What is this small Imperial ship with two dishes below it?

Tags: star-wars

I learned about interdiction in *Star Wars* (I thought it was just in EVE Online) by watching the fan [short film *TIE Fighter*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PN_CP4SuoTU), after wondering what those [Star Destroyers with lumpy growths](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Interdictor-class_Star_Destroyer) were, but where's another craft that I have no idea what it is (can't just look at Wookieepedia's Star Destroyer page).

Two of them are pictured below. Maybe they're some fighter support craft (a la Raptors in BSG), but I have no idea.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are "[Utility Tugs](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Utility_Tug)". They've not been seen in any of the films but they have made an appearance in several licensed PC games:

Per the Star Wars Wikia;

> The Tug was a common sight throughout the Galaxy, busily towing cargo
>   containers to and from the storage holds of freighters and spaceborne
>   trading outposts. The tiny craft's small size hid powerful tractor
>   beams that gave it the ability to manipulate and haul loads far
>   greater that its own mass.

[image]

Comment: Kinda strange that they're rolling out with the fighters...

Comment: @nickt - I thought that. They seem to disappear in the next scene.

Comment: @NickT - perhaps the fighters are escorting the tugs?

Comment: @Richard I could be wrong, but I think these are also a possible mount/vehicle in SWTOR. At the very least, there's one that's extremely similar.

Answer (score 4):

The Utility Tug comes from the X-Wing/TIE Fighter series of games from the early-mid 90's. In the later games, if they player's fighter ran out of missiles/torpedoes/etc during a mission, they could press Shift-B (if I remember correctly) to call one of these ships to dock with them for a few seconds and reload their warheads to full. The ships had no weapons and very little health, and would usually sit well out of the way until called. Eventually the Combat Utility Vehicle was created for the same purpose. I think the games also referenced them moving containers and ferrying pilots as well, but the most likely reason for being in formation with TIEs here (especially bombers) is missile resupply.

Comment: Which explains why they're rolling out with the TIE - fighters